# Generating a PKCS10 Certificate request with extra fields in java

Tags: java, certificate, x509certificate, pki, csr

I need to add extra fields in the CSR, like keyusage, regestrationID etc.I am using java IBM-sdk60. I've gone through x500 name API's and could not find any solution. Help on API's would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Which API are you using to generate the CSR?

Comment: Hi JCS...
Am using com.ibm.security.pkcs10.*; com.ibm.security.pkcsutil.*; com.ibm.security.x509.X500Name; where the standard CSR request consists of the fields CN,OU,O & C...
Now i also need to map new fields like EKU (Enhanced Key Usage) &  regestrationID. Am not finding a way to map those fileds.

Comment: String keyUsg = KeyUsageExtension.KEY_ENCIPHERMENT;
byte [] der =new DerValue(keyUsg).getOctetString();
KeyUsageExtension keyUsage = new KeyUsageExtension(true,der);
DerInputStream in = new DerInputStream(keyUsage.toString().getBytes());
PKCSAttributes attr=new PKCSAttributes(in,"IBMJCEFIPS");

I tried using the above code snippet to add KeyUsage extension to the certificate signing request, i get the following exception.

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: DerValue.getOctetString, not an Octet String: 12
@Jcs can u pls help me get through.

Comment: For an example using sun.security see http://dev.harpavieja.cz/gitweb/?p=webscarab/.git;a=commitdiff;h=147b6defa0b3ead354e6dc30f16a61b3223d8bf6 getCertificateExtensions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way to include additional information in a CSR (PKCS#10) request is by adding `Attributes`. According to the PKCS#10 standard:

> The intention of including a set of attributes is twofold: to provide
>   other information about a given entity , or a "challenge password" by
>   which the entity may later request certificate revocation; and to
>   provide attributes for inclusion in X.509 certificates.  A
>   non-exhaustive list of attributes is given in PKCS #9

An attribute is an *OID* and a value whose meaning depends on the OID

Actually [PKCS#9](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2131) defines 3 attributes:

- Challenge password
- Extension request
- Extended-certificate attributes (this is deprecated)

The one you are looking for is *Extension request* :

> The extensionRequest attribute type may be used to carry information
>   about certificate extensions the requester wishes to be included in a
>   certificate.

This code template (not tested) may give you some hints on how include this attribute

```
CertificateExtensions exts = /* build the extensions set you want to include */
/* Wrap the extensions set into a SET OF */
OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
exts.encode(out);
DerValue val = new DerValue(DerValue.tag_SetOf, out.toByteArray());
PKCSAttribute extReq = new PKCSAttribute(new ObjectIdentifier("1.2.840.113549.1.9.14"), val.toByteArray());
PKCSAttributes attrs = new PKCSAttributes(new PKCSAttribute[] { extReq });
CertificationRequestInfo cri = new CertificationRequestInfo(subject, key, attrs);
CertificationRequest csr = new CertificationRequest(cri);
```

Please note that unless the CA explicitly announces this PKCS#10 attribute is supported it  will be ignored during the certificate generation.

Comment: Thanks a lot JCS...
This is wat i am looking for...
And Yeah the CA supports the PKCS#10 attribute which am working on so i dont find any problem with the solution u've provided...